# '${path.module} in Terraform cannot find a file

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines

I need to run a Powershell file from Terraform. Here is my code :

```
resource "null_resource" "create-sql-user" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = ".'${path.module}\\CreateUser.ps1'"
    interpreter = ["pwsh", "-Command"]
  }

  depends_on = ["azurerm_mssql_server.main"]
}
```

It cannot find the file with ${path.module}. I am getting the error

```
Error: Error running command '.'.\CreateUser.ps1'': exit status 1. Output: .: The term '.\CreateUser.ps1' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
```

I have placed the ps1 file in the Terraform folder I am running from as a test so :

```
---> Terraform 
-----> CreateUser.ps1 
-----> Main.tf
-----> Outputs.tf
```

Surely {Path.module} relates to the folder with Main.tf inside of it?

Comment: I am not exactly the biggest powershell user, but the resolved string `.'.\CreateUser.ps1'` does not seem like a valid path, and that string does resolve as expected.

Comment: @MattSchuchard - i agree - it looks odd... i am just trying to follow the sketchy information avaiable and i need to see if anyone has done this - its not like i am trying to do something 'mental'... but its driving me crazy :) cheers

Comment: I also don't really know PowerShell but my first attempt here would've been to write `command = "${path.module}\\CreateUser.ps1"`, without the extra period and quotes. Does that first period and the quotes do something special in PowerShell syntax?